# R: Replacing object names with a list of characters

Tags: r, repeat

I have a couple of commands as such;

```
x_07 <- mean(df_07$y)
z_07 <- mean(df_07$b)
```

`_07` corresponds to 2007/ I would like to be able to replace the `_07` several times, all the way up to 2022 (i.e. 08, 09, 10, 11 etc) and save all of these objects in the workspace. Is there a fast way to do this?

I have tried using for-loops and such but I'm still quite new to this.

Answer (score 0):

use this function:

```
assign(x = 'name', value = 1)
> ls()
> "name"
```

edit: looking at primary point what you are trying to achieve. Easier way would be to use `colMeans()`, also you can explore `dplyr` and `tidyverse` packages for more diverse approaches.